# AttributeError: module 'unittest' has no attribute 'Testcase'

Tags: python

I am new with python, i am trying to fllow the tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tNS--WetLI&t=168s 
I have the error message 
code:

```
import unittest
import calc

class TestCalc(unittest.Testcase):
    def test_add(self):
        result=calc.add(10,5)
        self.assertEqual(result,15)

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestCalc)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

I already seen all the answer on stackoverflow but the error resist.

Please help

Comment: TestCase not Testcase....note the capital C

Comment: [It's `TestCase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) (note the case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a typo when writing the class name. It is with capitalized case `TestCase`, like you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).